# Exportando o meu banco de dados para CSV com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Eu criei um código em php que realiza uma busca no twitter e salva o resultado (100 tweets) em um banco de dados. Nesse código, eu também tenho a opção de selecionar todos os tweets do banco de dados e exporta-los para um arquivo csv.

Entretanto, se o tweet possuir um line break ele ficará dessa forma no csv:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O que eu faço para salvar esse tweet em apenas uma linha do csv (apagar o line break )

Este é o meu código que exporta os tweets para o csv:

```
// Database Connection

$host="xxxxxx";
$uname="xxxxx";
$pass="xxxxxx";
$database = "xxxxxx";   

$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 

echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database could not be selected");  
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");


// Fetch Record from Database

$output         = "";
$table          = "tabela_tweets_novo"; // Enter Your Table Name
$sql            = mysql_query("select tweet from $table");
$columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($sql);

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading    =   mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
    $output     .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}
$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {

$acentua = utf8_decode($row["$i"]);
$output .='"'.$acentua.'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename =  "UUXPost.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;
```

Comment: Eu fiz um com PDO que não teve problema com quebra de linha, veja se te ajuda. https://gist.github.com/rafa-acioly/0718d3a5d5b377108052

Comment: Só quero lembrar que o `mysql_*` está sendo descontinuado por questões de segurança. Eu recomendo que utilize `mysqli_*` ou PDO.

Answer (score 3):

consegui resolver adicionando essas 3 linhas

```
$acentua = utf8_decode($row["$i"]);    <- meu código

$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"); 
$replace = '<br />'; 
$acentua = str_replace($order, $replace, $acentua);

$output .='"'.$acentua.'",';            <- meu código
```